# .net blazor wasm testing bunit with localization

Tags: blazor-webassembly, bunit

I'm building a blazor webassembly site and I want to use bunit for testing purpose.

I run into trouble with components that use localization, I am getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> Cannot provide a value for property 'L' on type 'Path.To.Component'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer`1[Path.To.Component]'.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)

I already tried to install localization on the test project, but this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on the github discussion:

https://github.com/bUnit-dev/bUnit/discussions/239